# How can I set the size of edit controls in ASP.NET Dynamic Data details views?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

How can I, if I can, set the size of textboxes generated in the details and edit views of a Dynamic Data application, without resorting to custom page templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change ALL textboxes in the app, you should modify Text.ascx in the Fieldtemplates folder.  If you want to modify some text boxes, you should create a custom field template, and assign that control to the field in metadata like so :

```
[UIHint("TextWide")]
public object Description { get; set; }
```